# transforming triple integral from Cartesian to polar and solving it

Tags: calculus

The integral I'm trying to evaluate is the following $$\iiint\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2-z^2}}dxdydz$$ taking throughout the volume of the spare $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$ lying in the first octant

Answer is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$

I have tried it for past a week trying to get the answer . It requires transforming it back to polar coordinate which is what I'm not able to do convincingly. I need a detailed solution.  I have tried and have gotten questions similar but this is very convincing for me.  I will appreciate if someone can help me out in time,  it's likely it comes out in my exam next week. Thanks.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/288417) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Comment: Being new on MSE I want to tell you that if you find that one of the answers you get for the post solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted so that the MSE user gets the points and so that every other member on the site knows that this post is closed! It's nice, but not compulsory, even marking answers as useful if you find them so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first recall that $$r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$$ and that the Jacobian for the spherical coordinate is $$\det(J) = r^2\sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$$ and that $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, $r\in[0,1]$ and $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ because we're integrating over a sphere of radius 1.
Your integral then becomes $$\iiint\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}dxdydz = \color{red}{\frac{1}{8}}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1\frac{r^2sin(\theta)dr d\theta d \phi}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$
The red factor is there to take only one octant of the space (symmetry permits us to simplify our calculation like that, but we could do it by setting appropriate limits for integration).

Evaluating the integrals on the angels we get $$\frac{1}{8}\underbrace{2\pi}_{\phi\text{ integral }}\underbrace{2}_{\theta\text{ integral}}\int_0^1\frac{r^2dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ Making a substitution $r=\sin(t)$ the limits of integration becomes $$r=0 \Rightarrow t = 0\;\;\;\;\;r=1\Rightarrow t=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr$$ the integral simplifies to $$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi\over 2}\sin^2(t)dt = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

You want $\frac{1}{8}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\int_0^1\frac{r^2 dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{r^2 dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$. The substitution $r=\sin t$ lets us rewrite this as $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2 t dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$, where we have used the fact that $\sin^2 t$ averages to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the two correct answers,  but I wanted to understand also why the range of ϕ changes to [2pie,0] likewise the 1/8 behind, how did it get there?

Comment: @OlaniyiMichealmcolas As Davide Morgante noted, the $1/8$ factor is due to restriction to the positive octant, and each octant having the same contribution to an all-octants integral due to symmetry. If we had wanted all octants, the ranges of $\theta,\,\phi$ would respectively be $[0,\,\pi],\,0,\,2\pi]$; this is standard in the spherical polar coordinate system.